# jquery focusが効かない

Tags: jquery

以下のjqueryで受信データの内容で、focusを変更しているのですが、IEではうまくいくのですが、chromeでは全く効きません。ご教授ください。

```
    $.ajax(

            type: "POST", 
            url : "/aoi/TestServlet",
            dataType:"json",
            data: {"message" : requestJson}
        }
    ).done(
        function(data, status, xhr){
            $("#mes").text(data.mes);
            if(data.mes == null){
                setTimeout(function(){$('#meisyo').focus();}, 100);
            }else{
                setTimeout(function (){$("#code").focus();}, 100);
            }
        }
    ).fail(
        function(xhr, status, thrown){
            console.log("fail: status=" + status + "[" + xhr.status + "]");
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: 質問とは無関係ですが`{` が足りないように思います

Comment: jqueryのメソッドではなくDOMの`focus`メソッドを呼び出してみるのはどうですか。セレクタはidなので要素はひとつでしょうから、`$('#meisyo')[0].focus();`などとします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
やってみましたが、変わらずです。

Answer (score 1):

別のパソコンでやると正常に動作しました。
パソコンの不具合見たいです。
お騒がせしました。

Comment: 解決した場合には、自分自身で承認しておきましょう。